# I can't figure out how to get this sequence to converge to 0

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to prove this sequence converges to $0$ (or maybe I'm wrong..):
$$k\in\mathbb N,1<q,\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n^k}{q^n}$$
I'd be happy to get some help with this! thank you!

Comment: Fixed! thanks @quid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after long discussions about this problem I got a solution which doesn't use any of the suggested methods (such as limit of exponential's, logarithmic's, etc)
so my calculus course will accept it.
We find an $\alpha$ such that: (1) $\alpha^n>n^k$ $\land$ (2) $ 1\lt\alpha\lt q$

#### (1)

from the dense order of $\mathbb R$ and because $q>1$ then $\exists 1 \lt\alpha\lt q$

#### (2)

$\alpha^n>n^k \iff \alpha> \sqrt[n]{n}^k$ though $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{n}^k = 1^k = 1 \implies \exists N_0 \forall n>N_0 \,\mid\sqrt[n]{n}^k-1\,\mid<\frac{q-1}{2}$

#### from here

we choose $1<\frac{q-1}{2}<\alpha<q$ and we get $\frac{n^k}{q^n}<\frac{\alpha^n}{q^n}=(\frac{\alpha}{q})^n$ for $n>N_0$ though we know that
$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (\frac{\alpha}{q})^n = 0 \implies \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^k}{q^n} = 0$ from the squeeze theorem.

#### Wow! this is the first time I wrote something this long  here, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n=\frac{n^k}{q^n}$.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(n+1)^k}{q^{n+1}}/\frac{n^k}{q^n}=\frac{1}{q}\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^k=\frac{1}{q}\left(1+\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\right)^k=\frac{1}{q}$$

Hence there will be a $K$ after which the ratio is less than $b<1$ whenever $n\ge K$, so after that point it decreases exponentially. This is the same idea as in the proof of the [ratio test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#Ratio_test), which further shows that your sequence, when summed, is also convergent (this also implies that the terms of the series go to 0).

#### Details

$\exists K\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\forall n\ge K,\quad\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<b$ where $b\in(\frac{1}{q},1)$.

$\forall n>K,\quad 0\le a_n=\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}a_{n-1}\le ba_{n-1}\le \dots\le b^{n-K}a_K\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

By squeeze theorem, $a_n\to 0$.

Comment: We haven't studied ratio limits yet nor logarithmics on my calculus course, Is there a way to solve this without either?

Comment: See **Details**. As long as you learnt squeeze theorem and the limit of an exponential sequence, you can do this.

Comment: For the limit of an exponential sequence, use monotone convergence theorem and the trick with limits (see the answer by Hasan Saad).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** You are right. You may write, as $n$ is great:
$$
\log \left(\frac{n^k}{q^n}\right)=k \log n - n\log q=-n \left(\log q - k\frac{\log n}{n} \right)\sim -n \log q \longrightarrow -\infty
$$ thus your **initial sequence** is tending to $0^+$:
$$
\frac{n^k}{q^n}=e^{\log \left(\frac{n^k}{q^n}\right)} \longrightarrow e^{-\infty}=0
$$

Comment: To me, this doesn't seem any more obvious than the original sequence (?)

Comment: @MPW As $n$ is great:$$\frac{\log n}{n}= \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}\frac{\log \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}} \leq  \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}} \longrightarrow 0$$

Comment: How is this any different? The whole difficulty is to see that $\log x/x$ tends to zero as $x$ grows without bound. I suppose this is equivalent to showing that $xe^{-x}$ tends to zero, but I thing something should be said along those lines to justify it. I accept it, of course, but it may not be obvious to OP.

Comment: @MPW In my comment above, you will see that I've just assumed $\displaystyle 0\leq\frac{\log x}{x}\leq 1$, for $x$ great, giving $$0\leq \frac{\log n}{n}= \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}\frac{\log \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}} \leq  \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}$$ which gives the desired limit to $0$. Am I wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=(\frac{n+1}{n})^k*\frac{1}{q}$.

We have $q>1$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{n+1}{n})^k=1$.

Using the epsilon-delta definition, we have $N$ such that $(\frac{n+1}{n})^k<q\ \forall n>N$

Without loss of generality, assume it is so for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Thus, the sequence is decreasing, and we also have that it is bounded below by $0$. Thus, it is converging.

Denote the limit by $x$.$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}$

$x=\frac{1}{q}x$ and thus $x=0$